# gwtbootstrap3 Select - add Options

Tags: java, gwt, html-select, gwtbootstrap3

Using [GWTBootstrap3](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#select) how do I add options to the **select** ? And I don't find any method similar to `addOptions( )`.

I also tried `setValue(option)`, `setValues(option)`, `setValue(string)`, `setValues(string)`. But doesn't populate the select.

```
Option one = new Option( ); 
one.setText( "option one" ); 
one.setId( " " + i );

select.setValues( one ); 
select.refresh( );
```

Would prefer help on `addOptions( )` rather than `setValue( )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just add(Option)

```
select.add(one);
```